# Confused why Error resolved

Tags: c++, curl, linker-errors, libcurl

I am very very new to  C++ and I am trying to use `libcurl` to fetch the source of a URL with the following code:

```
#include<curl/curl.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

size_t curl_to_string(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *data) {
    std::string *str = (std::string *) data;
    char *sptr = (char *) ptr;
    unsigned int x;

    for (x = 0; x < size * nmemb; ++x) {
        (*str) += sptr[x];
    }

    return size * nmemb;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string pagedata;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.com");
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_to_string);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &pagedata);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    cout << pagedata << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have been getting linker error like :

```
undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt' updater.cpp /ATVSiteDBManager/src   line 30 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'   updater.cpp /ATVSiteDBManager/src   line 28 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt' updater.cpp /ATVSiteDBManager/src   line 32 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'    updater.cpp /ATVSiteDBManager/src   line 31 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'    updater.cpp /ATVSiteDBManager/src   line 35 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt' updater.cpp /ATVSiteDBManager/src   line 33 C/C++ Problem
```

I am using Eclipse. But to get it working none of the methods in the internet solved. I repeatedly tried `-lcurl` but it did not solve the issue. But the last thing I did was to copy the `libcurl.dll` from the `lib` directory of curl to the output directory and renamed a file named `libcurldll.a` to `libcurl.dll.a` in the same directory, which miraculously solved the problem and the code works fine.

Is it the correct way to accomplish this simple task without any side-effects?

Comment: The compiler usually looks up a file named `libcurl.a` when the `-lcurl` option is specified. `libcurldll.a` is just a stub for dynamic linking. You would have achieved the same effect by specifying `-lcurldll`, but I think Eclipse Builder might get this right anyway (library filenames with extensions `.dll.a`).

Comment: But there's also a `libcurl.a` file already present. Then why did the error happened?

Comment: Currently tried using `-llibcurl` instead of `-lcurl` with full luck.!!

Comment: I'd guess it has to do with the 'Shared Library Settings' used for your project in the 'C++ Build->Settings->GCC C++ Linker` project properties. What is configured there. **Note** Linking against `libcurl.a` is for static linkage, while `libcurldll.a` is for dynamic linkage. The results are different and behave differently.

Comment: Initially it was only `curl` in the `Libraries(-l)` box and the `path to Curl Lib Folder` in the `Library Search Path(-L)` box. Later I replaced the `curl` in the 1st box with `libcurl`[and also with `curldll`]. Note that I am using MinGW C++ Linker.

Comment: In any of the ways I have to copy the `libcurl.dll` to the executable path manually?

Comment: AFAIK with MinGw, you would either need to copy it there, or add the path where the .DLL can be found to the PATH variable (you might also try LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but AFAIR it didn't work).

Comment: In that case its okay that I am using the `-lcurldll`. Because its not a problem to move the DLL to the path of the exe after the build is complete.